PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 13): ‘Tis the Season for... Diamonds?
This puzzle is part of the Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2024. The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 150 reputation.< Previous Door Next Door >
‘Tis the season for... Diamonds? Wait a minute, that can’t be right. What are we supposed to be looking at?
After solving the grid, highlight the first instance of every clue’s first letter in the corresponding answer (where present). For example, if the clue starts with the letter A, highlight the first A of the answer in the grid.

Solve on Penpa+
Across
1. Stop inside and warn evacuated settlement (4)
3. Michael who makes critical documentaries is increasingly vocal (5)
6. The first "twinkle", in music flyer of old (4)
8. Green edible plant with rough surface (4)
10. Treeless expanse by the French Alps' edge (3)
11. Turn that's ever-changing? (4)
13. The style of Will Smith's filmography is entertaining (3)
16. Satisfied player from Queens (3)
17. Going around city on South America's west coast westwards, to understand nautical distance (3,4)
18. Ancient Anatolian square surrounds church (6)
19. Initially silent game at the casino leads to noisy arguments (6)
20. Singer Paul is the last to perform on record (4)
21. Lindsay, of Mean Girls fame, not the last to open with a local greeting (5)
22. Ecstasy and heroin smuggled in, for example, churned butter (4)
23. Bend stick hard making camp (6)
24. A king's taken off shoes, leading to derision (6)
26. Multiple collections of rough drafts, for small kids, beginners and so forth, TV network greenlights (11)
31. Murdered in Las Bananas (5)
34. Castling queenside is one way to win, 44 across being the other one (3)
35. Cuban journalist describes Paterson on tenner (5)
37. Place to retire for black journalist (3)
39. Recognisable mascot of university located in Texas (3)
40. Half native of 1 down maybe in Scotland (4)
41. Perhaps guy wearing eyeliner in political gathering loses head (3)
42. Members of parliament being surprisingly slow (4)
43. Space inside container carried by 45 across is large (5)
44. Vin Diesel vehicle showing alternative title for this puzzle? (3)
45. Jolly old elf that's played with Satan (5)
Down
1. I participated in an election as candidate in Troy, a capital city (6)
2. Feelings of unease in sauna? Use a sponge! (7)
4. Soviet Olympian Korbut shot goal (4)
5. Portrayer of Freddie in film: "In retrospect, you may refer to me as a Republican" (4)
6. Cleanse the insides of Eden – it's very grand – before the End of Time (7)
7. Tube's burst under the surface of ocean that's dense (6)
8. One comes from a press writhing in pain (6)
9. Perform and create new production? (7)
11. For instance, Cameroon prison is included in volume #7 of encyclopaedia (7)
12. Hollow pole pierces backside, leading to death (6)
14. Gregory from Hollywood is scratching head a little bit (4)
15. Smear Ms Zappa endlessly in school (6)
16. Sound of bass guitar effect starts to muffle? Wear amplifying headphones! (4)
23. Rock group in Woodstock is short-lived (4)
25. Poles try to raise alternative to "marry" and "avoid", on British TV (4)
27. Snake appearing in book (Bible's first) near a hallowed place (5)
28. Enigma's output, say: Adults-only manuscript book (5)
29. Treatment for wrinkles to split container (5)
30. Present wrapped in skin regularly recognised (5)
32. Student with fully unlimited pause in activity (4)
33. Upcoming Mattel doll has carbon cervix (4)
35. Team owner Jerry Jones ultimately supports public transport (4)
36. Openings for jobs overlooked, leaving trainees in shock (4)
38. Sport for cyclists born before 2010 lacking central component (3, abbr.)

We should be looking at...

 MISTLETOES! Fittingly, there are synonyms of kiss under each diamond.

Clue answers:
Across:

1. _TO_+W_N
3. MOORE ("more")
6. DO DO (solfege)
8. PEA+R_
10. LE+A_
11. VEER*
13. _RAP_
16. MET (ddef)
17. SE(AMIL<)E
18. NI(CE)NE
19. S_+CRAPS
20. ANKA ("anchor")
21. A+LOHA(-n)
22. G(H+E)E<
23. KITSC*+H
24. SNE(-ak)ERS
26. S_ K_+ETC+HBO+OKS
31. SLAIN*
34. OOO (ddef)
35. _BAN JO_
37. B+ED
39. T(U)X
40. ALBA(-nian)
41. (-d)EMO
42. OWLS*
43. S(L)ACK
44. XXX (ddef)
45. SANTA*

Down:

1. T(I+RAN)A
2. _NA USE A S_
4. OLGA*
5. (R A M'I)<
6. _DE_ _T_ _ER_ + G + _E
7. O_+BTUSE*
8. PANINI*
9. REENACT*
11. VOL(CAN)_O_
12. REA(P_E)R
14. (-s)PECK
15. S(MOO(-n))CH
16. MWAH (inits)
23. _K IS S_
25. SN<+OG<
27. KAA+B_+A
28. CODE+X
29. BO(TO)X
30. _K(NOW)_N
32. L+_ULL_
33. NE(C)K<
35. BUS+_S
36. JOLT (inits)
38. B+M(-m)X


Can you provide the answers as text? That image is horribly pixelated.
